# Which river is the treasure in?

Tags: rebus

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus): [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus).</sup></sup>

---

You are a renowned treasure hunter, and using your puzzling skills, you have found that an ancient treasure on the bottom of "_ _ _ _ River" in Spain. But, which river? You have a feeling the answer may lie in these mysterious rebuses that you found in Italy a few days ago...

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

A four letter word from 5 rebuses? No problem for you, your puzzling skills will soon figure this out...right?

Hint:

> This is actually a very simple puzzle. Not all the rebuses are two words.

Comment: Are you going to add a hint for Rebus#3?

Comment: Would it require any knowledge about spanish language?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Nope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Partial solution**:

First rebus

> might be BUG NUTS, if the car is meant to be a VW Beetle ("Bug").

Second rebus

> surely SCOT FREE (the flag shown is that of Scotland).

Third rebus

> I have no idea about at present.

Fourth rebus

> TOP DRAWER, I assume.

Fifth rebus

> well, the busts are of Julius Caesar. It should probably be obvious to me what to do with ten Julius Caesar busts, but right now it isn't. They're laid out like a phone keypad but if that's more than coincidence I don't yet see what to do with it. (CAESAR PHONE -> SOUSAPHONE? JULIUS KEYPAD? HEADPHONE? All nonsense.)

So we have, maybe,

> BUG NUTS
>  SCOT FREE
>  ? ?
>  TOP DRAWER
>  ? ?

where I'm guessing that

> all rebus solutions will turn out to be two-word phrases. The fact that the last letter of the first one is the first letter of the next suggests an obvious way to get four letters, but unfortunately that seems to lead to SETR which, um, doesn't sound like the name of a river in Spain. Another possibility is that the last rebus means "Caesar shift by 10" and should be applied to the results of the other four, after reducing each somehow to a single letter.

I also remark (though I don't know whether it helps) that

> the rebus solutions we have so far all look kinda cryptic-clue-y. BUG NUTS could indicate that we should take an anagram of either BUG or NUTS. SCOT FREE could indicate an anagram of SCOT. TOP DRAWER could mean the letter D.

What rivers are there in Spain?

> Wikipedia yields the following four-letter ones; I may well have missed some. Ason, Avia, Deva, Ebro, Esla, Foix, Gaia, Muga, Oria, Saja, Tajo, Viar.

Comment: You have the second and fourth rebuses correct

Comment: Oh, the first one is correct also

Comment: 5 may be Roman numerals

Comment: It's likely irrelevant since it doesn't fit the two-word pattern, but TEN (Caesar shifted 1) is UFO.

Comment: Could three be 'don't count your chickens before they hatch' or some short summary of that?

Comment: Yeah, could be. Not obvious why three in particular, but I suppose one would have to choose *some* number :-). It would be a bit of a departure from the two-word-phrase pattern in the others.

Comment: Maybe all the rebuses give us four clues that happen to be letters that are roman numerals, which we then convert into letters to get the answer?

Comment: If the nuts in #1 were mine and I was in the driver's seat, you could say I was... [you know](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Driving%20me%20nuts)

Comment: @humn That's another correct answer to the first rebus

Comment: @suomynonA How can a single rebus have 2 correct answers? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot It's also a hint that certain parts of the rebus don't matter

Comment: I know this is pretty late but... OP has mentioned that not all the rebus are pertinent. Soooooo maybe the second is not part of the rebus (SCOT FREE, rebus free of Scot) and perhaps 3 is unimportant too (there is a red circle with a line through it – perhaps saying it should be removed?)

Comment: Hm. This answer just got accepted, but it doesn't seem to me like I solved everything...